# Syntax error install xampp in ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, server, xampp

i faced problem while im trying to install xampp on ubuntu mate 16.04
i follow this steps  :

1 - `chmod 755 installer.run`

2 - `./installer.run`
but i got problem"

`./xampp-linux-x64-7.1.1-0-installer.run: 1: ./xampp-linux-x64-7.1.1-0-installer.run: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string "`

any solution to install xampp or lamp ?

[screen shot for problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR7b2.png)

Answer (score 0):

This answer by [Terrance](https://askubuntu.com/users/231142/terrance) was [posted on the Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/674519):

> Judging by the error you are getting, and found on this site [here](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=244870&sid=149d2efb396bdfee33a29bd2df9e7954), the
>   error can occur when you are installing a `64bit` version of the program
>   on a `32bit` system.
>
> What does the command `uname -a` return on your system? If you see
>   anything other than x64 in that line, then download the `32bit` version
>   of the application.
>
> Hope this helps!

Comment: can u give me link for 32 version because i cant found it on apachefriends.org site ?

Comment: I can't find it either.